# How to store the output(even errors/warning) of sql queries in a file when ran in python script?

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7

I'm running sql queries using python script on windows using Python IDE.

Following is my sample code to connext to DB and execute the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb
import sys
import cProfile
import re
import timeit

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","bala","bala","mydb" )


# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

import time
start_time = time.time()

// This is simple query, I was running different query,
sqlstr = "SELECT * from accounts"

cursor.execute(sqlstr)
db.commit()

print("--- %s micro seconds ---",  time.time() - start_time)
print  cursor.fetchall()
```

After running this script it gives output on console, However I want to store it in a file or string variable at least. It might results into errors or warnings, even that also can be stored in file/string.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb
import sys
import cProfile
import re
import timeit

file = open("filename.txt","w")
# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","bala","bala","mydb" )


# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

import time
start_time = time.time()

// This is simple query, I was running different query,
sqlstr = "SELECT * from accounts"
try :    
    a = cursor.execute(sqlstr)
    for i in a :
        file.write(i)
    db.commit()
except :
    file.write(a)

print("--- %s micro seconds ---",  time.time() - start_time)
print  cursor.fetchall()
```

this may work !
I have opened a file where "filename" is name of your file and opened it in write mod and written output of your query line by line in the file having file name "filename". for error I have used try and except method.